# Add multiple style based on hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have the following **HTML** layout:

```
<!-- start stars -->
<span class="spr-starratings spr-review-header-starratings" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
    <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
    <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
    <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
    <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
</span>
<!-- end stars -->
```

For example; if the 4th `<i>` is hovered, I want the first 3 plus that 1 to dynamically add some CSS `color: #f2d253;` and then when removing the cursor from that star I want it to reset the styles.

I'd like this done using jQuery if possible?

Any point in the direction would be appreciated, an example would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is also possible to do so using pure CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/4rpw7/.

HTML:

```
<span>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}

span > i {
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span > i:not(:last-child) {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

span > i:hover, span > i:hover ~ i {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What an incredible solution! congrats for that!

Answer (score 1):

prevAll() should do the trick - http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

Comment: That looks perfect, thank you for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: If you showed an example of usage that was relevant to the markup the OP provided, you'd probably get more upvotes to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhq2j/

CSS:

```
i.highlight { color: #f2d253; }
```

Jquery:

```
$('i').hover(
    function(){
        var prev = $(this).prevAll();
        $(this).add(prev).addClass('highlight');
    }, function() {
        $('i').removeClass('highlight');
});
```